# Cassandra: Why do I not have to include all partition keys in query?

Tags: database, cassandra

Currently, I am dealing with Cassandra.

While reading a blog post, it is said:

> When issuing a CQL query, you must include all partition key columns,
>   at a minimum.
>   (https://shermandigital.com/blog/designing-a-cassandra-data-model/)

However, in my database it seems like it possible without including all partition keys. Here the table:

```
CREATE TABLE usertable (
    personid text,
    name text,
    "timestamp" timestamp,
    active boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((personid, name), timestamp)
) WITH
  CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("timestamp" DESC)
  AND comment=''
  AND read_repair_chance=0
  AND dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.1
  AND gc_grace_seconds=864000
  AND bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.01
  AND compaction={ 'class':'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',
  'max_threshold':'32',
  'min_threshold':'4' }
  AND compression={ 'chunk_length_in_kb':'64',
  'class':'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
  AND caching={ 'keys':'ALL',
  'rows_per_partition':'NONE' }
  AND default_time_to_live=0
  AND id='23ff16b0-c400-11e8-55c7-2b453518a213'
  AND min_index_interval=128
  AND max_index_interval=2048
  AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0
  AND speculative_retry='99PERCENTILE';
```

So I can do `select * from usertable where personid = 'ABC-02';`. However, according to the blog post, I have to include `timestamp` as well.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cassandra, partition key spreads data around cluster. It computes the hash of partition key and determine the location of data in the cluster.

One exception is, if you use ALLOW FILTERING or secondary index it does not require you too include all partition keys in where query.

For further information take a look at blog post:

> The purpose of a partition key is to split the data into partitions
>   where an entire partition is stored on a single node in the cluster
>   (with each node storing many partitions). When data is read or written
>   from the cluster, a function called Partitioner is used to compute the
>   hash value of the partition key. This hash value is used to determine
>   the node/partition which contains that row. The clustering key is used
>   further to search for a row within a given partition.
>
> Select queries in Apache Cassandra look a lot like select queries from
>   a relational database. However, they are significantly more
>   restricted. The attributes allowed in ‘where’ clause of Cassandra
>   query must include the full partition key and additional clauses may
>   only reference the clustering key columns or a secondary index of the
>   table being queried.
>
> Requiring the partition key attributes in the ‘where’ helps Cassandra
>   to maintain constant result-set retrieval time as the cluster is
>   scaled-out by allowing Cassandra to determine the partition, and thus
>   the node (and even data files on disk), that the query must be
>   directed to.
>
> If a query does not specify the values for all the columns from the
>   primary key  in the ‘where’ clause, Cassandra will not execute it and
>   give the following warning :
>
> ‘InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>   message=”Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering
>   and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute
>   this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW
>   FILTERING” ‘

https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-cassandra-scalability-allow-filtering-partition-keys/

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

According to your schema, your timestamp column is the clustering column, the sorting column, no part of the partition key. That’s why it is not required.

(personid, name) are your partitions columns.